# Form is ignoring the code in OnOpen event

Tags: ms-access, vba

Have a new form that contains controls and is linked to a table in SQL Server. Have code that relinks the table on open, and that code works in 5 other apps, but not this one.  Here is the code:

```
  Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
  For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
  ' check if table is a linked table
  If Len(tdf.Connect) > 0 Then
  tdf.Connect = "Connect String"
  tdf.RefreshLink
  End If
  Next
```

I had the form set up in options to open when the app is activated,  but it ask for the password which I have in the connect string.  I have entered a stop on a line of code in the in open event, but that code never executes.  It's like the onopen event is being ignored.

Thanks
jpl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access wants to load the data of a bound form **before** the `On Open` event runs. I guess in your other applications the start form is unbound.

Your best way around this is:

Create an [`AutoExec` macro](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-macro-that-runs-when-you-open-a-database-3a76b91c-99b6-46a3-93f3-5aebdeedaa81) that calls a public function with your relink code.

After that the function can open your bound start form

Comment: How can I tell if the form is bound and to what. On the form I have a listbox whose record source is a query, but in the data tab of properties for the form there is no record source. So what could it be bound to??

Comment: @user3216034: Well, you wrote "a form that contains controls **and is linked to a table in SQL Server**". If it has no record source, it is unbound. But the same effect applies to the bound list box. If you have any control bound (or with a row source) to a table or query, their data will be loaded before OnOpen.

Comment: For clarity, there is one listbox that contains a query that accesses a table in SQL Server.  That's it.  All other controls have data that was entered during their creation. If I understand what you wrote, that one listbox is the culprit, is that correct? And there is no record source for the form itself.

Comment: Reading up on autoexec macros.  Never used macros before.

Comment: Yes, the list box will access the data and cause the password prompt. An Autoexec macro calling an init function will be the only macro you need. :)