# using autoexec to link tables prior to on open event

Tags: ms-access, vba

This question follows a previous question [Form is ignoring the code in OnOpen event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328423/form-is-ignoring-the-code-in-onopen-event) that was answered by Andre.

I have a form that is bound by a control that executes a query, so I can't use the onopen event to relink tables when the form is opened. I have created a function as follows:

```
Function AutolinkDB()
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef

    For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        ' check if table is a linked table
        If Len(tdf.Connect) > 0 Then
            tdf.Connect = "Connect String"
            tdf.RefreshLink
        End If
    Next

    ''' Andre edit: after relinking the tables, open the start form
    DoCmd.OpenForm "loginputFrm"
    ''' Andre edit

End Function
```

Next, I created an autoexec macro that looks like the following:

```
OpenForm
  Form Name loginputFrm
         View Form
  Filter Name
Where Condition
         Data Mode
  Window Mode  Normal
RunCode
  Function Name Autolink()
```

Problem is that the autolink does not execute the function, and app still asks for manual password.

Comment: Please explain further: *form that is bound by a control that executes a query*...forms are bound by recordsources. Are you auto-updating such recordsources on the form's `OnOpen` event? Please post this trigger event's VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **only** thing in your AutoExec macro should be

```
RunCode -> AutolinkDB()
```

(Note that you currently have `Autolink()` - typo?)

Nothing else. At the end of `AutolinkDB()`, open your start form with `DoCmd.OpenForm`.

Otherwise the form will be opened first, and ODBC data accessed.

Comment: It was a typo in RunCode.  It reads Function Name  AutolinkDB(). I have the form to open in Options >Current Database > Display Form: loginputFrm. Should it be none? I am not clear where to put the DoCmd.OpenForm, on the same line as the Run Code? Never did this before, so fuzzy.  Thanks

Comment: @user3216034: I took the liberty of editing it into your question.

Comment: Finally got it going.  The problem was that I didn't save the Macro as AutoExec.  Once I did that it ran fine.